# Specifying error message from SSIS Catalog Package execution in Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have the following problem. I have a job that has an SSIS Catalog Package execution in one of its steps. When one of the steps throws an error, I handle the error in another step where I query `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` and the column `message`, that has the error of the step. In general, all other steps handle errors by catching them and using `RAISERROR` with a custom message specified by requirement.

The problem is that when the package fails, even though I catch the package error inside it and use an SQL Task with a `RAISERROR` statement, when I query the `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` table, I find a generic message from the SSIS Catalog saying I should check the project's report for more details (and there, I find the custom message).

Is there anyway to avoid having that message appear in the job's history, instead making the custom one appear without anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Job starting SSIS package does simply call DTSExec with parameters translated from job definition screen. This stub error message is one produced by DTExec, you have little chance to alter it.
What you can do about it - for SSIS Package execution step parse this message, extracting `Execution ID: <ExecID>`. Then with this Execution ID - go to [SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877994.aspx), filter it by `operation_id = ExecID`, and lookup for rows with `message_type IN (120, 100)`. Contents of `message` field contains your error or cancellation messages.